# Поменять местами наибольший и наименьший элементы каждой строки матрицы

Tags: java, массивы, матрицы

Есть код ввода массива с клавиатуры. Необходимо, чтобы после ввода размеров массива выводилась исходная матрица и матрица, в которой по каждой строке были заменены минимальные и максимальные значения

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //Создание и заполнение массива
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Укажите количество столбцов прямоугольной матрицы: ");
    int n = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Укажите количество строк прямоугольной матрицы: ");
    int m = in.nextInt();
    int[][] pramMMassiv = new int[m][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
        {
            pramMMassiv[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 100)-50;
        }
    }
    //Вывод массива
    System.out.print("\nМатрица:");
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        System.out.println(" ");
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%5d", pramMMassiv [i][j]);
        }
    }
    int[] minPos = new int[5];
    int[] maxPos = new int[5];
    int temp;
    int min=0, max=0;
    for(int i = 0; i<pramMMassiv.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<pramMMassiv.length; j++) {
            if(min>pramMMassiv[j][0]){
                        min = pramMMassiv[j][0];
                 minPos[0] = i;
                minPos[1] = j;
            }
            if (max<pramMMassiv[j][0]){
                        max = pramMMassiv[j][0];
                maxPos[0] = i;
                maxPos[1] = j;
            }
        }
    }
    temp = pramMMassiv[minPos[0]][minPos[1]];
    pramMMassiv[minPos[0]][minPos[1]] = pramMMassiv[maxPos[0]][maxPos[1]];
    pramMMassiv[maxPos[0]][maxPos[1]] = temp;
    System.out.print("\nМатрица:");
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        System.out.println(" ");
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%5d", pramMMassiv [i][j]);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю, нужно как-то так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Создание и заполнение массива
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Укажите количество столбцов прямоугольной матрицы: ");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Укажите количество строк прямоугольной матрицы: ");
        int m = in.nextInt();
        int[][] pramMMassiv = new int[m][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                pramMMassiv[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 100) - 50;
            }
        }
        //Вывод массива
        System.out.print("\nМатрица:");
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            System.out.println(" ");
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%5d", pramMMassiv[i][j]);
            }
        }
        int[] minPos = new int[2];
        int[] maxPos = new int[2];
        int temp;
        int min, max;

        for (int i = 0; i < pramMMassiv.length; i++) {
            min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

            for (int j = 0; j < pramMMassiv[i].length; j++) {
                if (min >= pramMMassiv[i][j]) {
                    min = pramMMassiv[i][j];
                    minPos[0] = i;
                    minPos[1] = j;
                }
                if (max <= pramMMassiv[i][j]) {
                    max = pramMMassiv[i][j];
                    maxPos[0] = i;
                    maxPos[1] = j;
                }
            }

            temp = pramMMassiv[minPos[0]][minPos[1]];
            pramMMassiv[minPos[0]][minPos[1]] = pramMMassiv[maxPos[0]][maxPos[1]];
            pramMMassiv[maxPos[0]][maxPos[1]] = temp;
        }

        System.out.print("\nМатрица:");
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            System.out.println(" ");
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%5d", pramMMassiv[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
```